# Reading in a list of numbers from a file C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read in a list of numbers from a file into an array using scanf. then to print out the array.

The list is composed of over a thousand numbers but for an example it looks like this.

```
70.3
71.5
70.1
71.1
71.8
71.6
72.0
72.0
71.8
```

I have this much but, it only prints out a list of incomprehensible numbers.

```
int main () {

FILE *temp;
temp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
int Readings[2881];
int Temps;

    if (!temp)
    {
        printf("Cannot open the file!\n");
        return 0;
    }

for (Temps = 0; Temps < 2881; Temps++)
{
    fscanf (temp, "%d", &Readings[Temps]);
}

for (Temps = 0; Temps < 2881; Temps++)
{
    printf("The readings are %d\n", Readings[Temps]);
}

fclose(temp);

return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The values in your example are floating point but you are trying to read as integers.

Answer (score 5):

You are using %d when you should be using %f, and declaring Readings[] to be double.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems.

1. You have a list of real numbers in your file but you have declared an array of `int`s. Once you change the data type to `float Readings[2881];` or `double Readings[2881];`, you can start reading them in.
2. If you decide to use `float Readings[2881];`, change your `fscanf` statement to `fscanf (temp, "%f", &Readings[Temps]);`. If you decide to use `doulbe Readings[2881];`, change your `fscanf` statement to `fscanf (temp, "%lf", &Readings[Temps]);`

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is the format specifier for an integer but you are reading floating point numbers - use `%f` instead.